# how to track pageviews of a website without knowing its domain name?

Tags: javascript

first of all let me make it clear that it is nothing like illegal.

I have made a html code and published it on the internet anyone can easily copy the code and use it as per their requirements. Now because i want to check that how much popular my code is, i want to track that **how many times a website with my code is loded in a browser.**

I thought google analytics will be a good option but they want the the url of the website to be tracked but my code is openly uploaded and can be used by anyone, **i never know on which url it is implemented.** So can anyone help me out.

**If possible i would like to get the information that on what url it is implemented.**

Any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: suggest an edit with proper tags i have no idea about tags so i have used only javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of alternates for Google Analytics. One of them - [Clicky](http://getclicky.com).
You can try to use Clicky API http://getclicky.com/help/#/help/api

Comment: it may be awesome but as i said i don't know the url of the website. So it is no good for me.